# Execute AppInsight query via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am looking for a feature where i can fire appinsight query via REST API.

I am currently scanning logs using the query executor as shown below..

```
traces
| where message contains "something"
| order by timestamp desc
```

I want to integrate this with my REST application so that i don't have to login to appinsight and execute this query manually.

Is there an API available , that exposes such a feature where i can dynamically pass a query / execute a stored(custom) query and get the output as response?

Comment: First hit on google: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: how to construct the query url:**

You need to get the `Application Id` and `API key`, then use them to build your query url.

Step 1: Get `Application Id`. Nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> API Access. then you can see the `Application Id`:

[image]

Step 2: then click the "Create API key" button, in the new page, do something as per the screenshot below -> then click the "Generate key" button:

[image]

Step 3: in the new page, copy and save the API key:

[image]

Step 4: then go to this [link](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query) -> fill in all the necessary information -> then in the right pane, you can see it auto generates a url. Screenshot as below:

[image]

---

**Original:**

Yes, you can use the `application insights` [get-query api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference/get-query).

For how to use this api, please refer to this [quickstart](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) for more details.

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I use appinsight on azure portal. How do i construct my URL to access the  specific subscription and resource group via api?

Comment: @Jcoder, do you actually mean how construct the URL to query your appinsights?

Comment: Yes Ivan. That's what i meant.

Comment: @Jcoder, I've added it in my answer. Please take a look, and let me know if you still have issues:).

Comment: All links are no longer valid